# Python3: как сделать файл скрытым в windows?

Tags: python, windows, файлы, python-3.x

Как сделать файл скрытым в windows средствами Python3?

Answer (score 1):

Просто выполните команду [`attrib`](http://www.windowsfaq.ru/content/view/253/57/) с соответствующим параметром с помощью модуля [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['attrib', '+h', filename])
```

P.S. Должно работать, но у меня нет Windows, чтоб проверить. Так что, если что, пишите, будем разбираться.

Comment: можно еще так:  p = subprocess.Popen("attrib +h %s" % filename); out = p.stdout.read() так можно посмотреть что выдала программа attrib (в linux прокатывает)

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать с помощью ctypes:

```
import ctypes
kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
fileName = r'c:\_tmp\file.txt'
attr = kernel32.GetFileAttributesW(fileName)
kernel32.SetFileAttributesW(fileName, attr | 2)
```